# How to generate all possible combinations in a dictionary in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations

So I have a dict in a dict like so:

```
{'d': {'c': 3}, 'c': {'d': 3, 'b': 2}, 'b': {'c': 2, 'a': 1}, 'a': {'b': 1}}
```

And I need python code to give an output of :

```
("d","c")
("c","d")
("c","b")
("b","c")
("b","a")
("a","b")
```

I have no clue how to do this and any help is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with `dict.items`:

```py
dct = {'d': {'c': 3}, 'c': {'d': 3, 'b': 2}, 'b': {'c': 2, 'a': 1}, 'a': {'b': 1}}

output = [(key_1, key_2) for key_1, subdct in dct.items() for key_2 in subdct]
print(output) # [('d', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('a', 'b')]
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for answering

Answer (score 2):

```
x = {'d': {'c': 3}, 'c': {'d': 3, 'b': 2}, 'b': {'c': 2, 'a': 1}, 'a': {'b': 1}}

for i in x.keys():
  for j in x.get(i).keys():
    print((i,j))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {'d': {'c': 3}, 'c': {'d': 3, 'b': 2}, 'b': {'c': 2, 'a': 1}, 'a': {'b': 1}}

[(k1,k2) for k1 in dict1.keys() for k2 in dict1[k1].keys()]
```